# Get value of object inside of array which is inside an object itself

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I have a quick question which I seem to be tripped up on.

I have a data structure like so:

```js
data: {
   accounts: [{
      info: false
   }]
}
```

Is there a "fancy" **React** way for me to get the value of the boolean associated with the `info` key?

I can of course retrieve the value with using `map` or `find`, but it always ends up being somewhat convoluted or involved code.

If I do something like

```js
const { accounts } = data;
const customer = accounts.map(a => a.info);
```

The value for `customer` always ends up coming back as `[false]` instead of just `false`, which is really confusing me, because I am not sure why it would come back inside of an array, where it is not an array to begin with, and it is being mapped out of an array (`accounts`).

I had the same result when using `forEach` and `find`.

Is there something I'm missing? There has to be a quick Reactive one-liner to get the boolean value I'm looking for, and set it to a variable.

Anyone...?

Comment: No. It's just `data.accounts[0].info`. React is a DOM manipulation/abstraction framework, it isn't anywhere in this problem space. Also, `map` is a function that takes an array and returns an array with the callback applied to each item in the array, so I don't understand why you're surprised you wound up with an array from calling it?

Comment: `array.map` will always return an array.

Comment: @JaredSmith -- I seem to have had a brain fart with `map`. I have been using it in tandem with a bunch of other Lodash methods, and got mixed up. So yea, that makes sense. I thought there may have been a different way in doing this then using `[0]`. Thanks for your input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.accounts[0].info
```

or

Using [underscore.js](https://underscorejs.org/)

```
_.first(data.accounts).info
```